# cocos2d: Show entire layer then zoom in on character

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have my main game layer that is larger than the screen when the scene currently starts you see the character (a ship in this case) in the screen but I want to show the entire layer to the user first, and then animate back a zoom level of 1.

How can I achieve this? I know I can use the `scale` property on `CCLayer` but how can I tell how much of the view I am seeing such that I can show all of it?

Comment: it would help to know more about how your building the layer, is it tile based?  Also, how big is the ship (vs the screen at least, or in pixels).  Is the entire world larger then the screen?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but can't you use the scale property in conjunction with the size of the layer and size of the screen to know how much is being shown?

Comment: @Almo How do I animate the zoom? I suppose I could figure out the zoom size based on the layer size. nycynik the ship is tiny compared to the current viewport / layer.

Comment: Personally, assuming there are no cocos built-in effects for that, I would change the scale each frame by an amount modified by the current framerate so it's consistent across devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animate your zoom using a CCAction such as `CCScaleTo` and set the end scale of the zoom in the CCScaleTo action to whatever you want as derived by comparing the screensize to the layer size. For example, to zoom in to a 2X magnification, your CCScaleTo would scale to a 2.0 scale. You could get even fancier and use the size of a particular object in the layer in comparison to the size of the layer and size of the screen to calculate a scale that brings the desired object to exactly the size you want after zooming.

Comment: This seems like its what I want, got an example code to help me get started? Thanks